# Flex/AIR: call JSFL

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air, jsfl

I've written a JSFL file to publish some fla's, and now I'd like to call that script from a flex / AIR application.

So the user should browse to the JSFL-file and select it. After selecting the JSFL-file should run and do whatever is described in the JSFL. If I run the JSFL, no problems occur and everything goes fine. However, I can't seem to call the file from my flex/AIR application.

I've tried writing a flash AS3.0 file and call the JSFL from there but that doesn't work either.

The function I use is MMExecute but still nothing ... Searched for it quite some time now and I'd really like to do this. Anyway, here's some code...

```
//ABOVE IS THE SELECT EVENT
jsflpath = evt.target.nativePath;
MMExecute('fl.runScript("'+filePath+'" );');
```

Comment: MMExecute works in Flash Panel, so unless your swf is in the WindowSWF folder in the Flash configuration directory, it won't do anything. You need to call the Flash executable with the path to you jsfl script as the first argument from AIR (native api should help with that).

Answer (score 1):

George is exactly right. With AIR 2.0+, you could use *NativeApplication* to launch the script file directly in Flash.

More on *NativeApplication* here:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html
- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html